# Why is the webview displaying ‘no permission to load’ error when testing from within the super-app?

Tags: webview, vodapay-miniprogram

I am using the webview component to render a webpage in my mini program. In the simulator, the component works as expected, however, when I test it on my android app, I get the error shown in the image. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check to see if you have whitelisted the URL that you are trying to access in your mini program’s configuration section on your workspace. Please also note that the simulator supports displaying a webpage hosted locally, however, when you want to test on device, you need to host your site online.

[image]