# Error in mini program: The page is not allowed to load

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

My miniprogram loads in the miniprogram studio emulator but I get this error after releasing it to the super app. The app uses web-view to link to an external site. [image: miniprogram error]

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68415044/why-is-the-webview-displaying-no-permission-to-load-error-when-testing-from-wi

Comment: Hi, its definitely a duplication of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68415044/why-is-the-webview-displaying-no-permission-to-load-error-when-testing-from-wi